# Node: How to access flags, instead of arguments

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, flags

In my command-line application, I am wanting to print out either:

1. The entire command line that launched the application
2. The individual flags and arguments
3. Likely, both.

From `process.argv`, I can access the application I'm running  ([0]: `node.exe`), the file I'm running ([1]: `app.js`), and the rest of the passed arguments.  However the Node flag I am passing is not part of the array.

So, for instance, for my memory-intensive application, my command is:

> node --max-old-space-size=10240 app.js 18 false

And my `process.argv` array is:

```
0:'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe'
1:'d:\\Repos\\exampleApp\\app.js'
2:'18'
3:'false'
```

As you can see, there is no reference to the Node flag `max-old-space-size` (really a V8 flag, that's passed along)

So, ultimately, I am trying to access this passed-flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_execargv), it looks like `process.execArgv` is the property that provides these flags.  Like `process.argv`, this will be an array.  The docs refers to these as "Node.js-specific command-line options", rather than "Node.js flags".

So, for the example command:

> node --max-old-space-size=10240 app.js 18 false

... the `process.execArgv` array will be:

```
0: '--max-old-space-size=10240'
```